# Can't add Bamboo job requirements

Tags: bamboo

I have two agents, one with Myvenv and one without it. To build my application, i need the capability Myvenv. To make sure my application only builds on the agent WITH Myvenv, i wanted to add a requirement to the build job.
Visiting the `Configuration of the application -> Requirements -> Add`
When i add the following rule: `Myvenv exists`.
Bamboo won't stop loading.

This is for all Bamboo Requirements i try to add, why doens't it add the requirement? Or is there a other solution to my problem mentioned above?

Added screenshot, with small loading circle
[image]

Solution: 
Adding a requirement doens't work in Chrome or Firefox, but it does work in IE 11. Thanks to Rich Duncan

Comment: Not sure what you mean by won't stop loading.  Screenshot?

Comment: @RichDuncan I added a screenshot. (The arrow points to the spinning loading icon.)

Comment: That's strange - So you (1) press the add button and (2) you get the loading spinner but it never goes away.  I guess I would check the logs to see if there's any explanation

Comment: Yeah, thats exacly what's happening... But I don't see anything strange in the logs, except that there's only GET requests, no POSTs...

Comment: So if you don't find anything conclusive in the logs, I would think about (1) switching browsers.  I've seen AJAX behavior like this work one way in Chrome and another in Firefox. or (2) see what the heap max is for the bamboo server and think about increasing it (or monitor it and if necessary increase it).

Comment: Option 1 worked, Chrome and Firefox both didn't work, but when I tried it in IE 11 it did. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would look in the bamboo logs.  If you don't find anything conclusive in the logs, I would try switching browsers. I've seen AJAX behavior like this work one way in Chrome and another in Firefox.